# Is it possible to grayscale a MPO file (3D camera) for a CNC carving

Tags: 3d-printing, cnc

I had/have a 3D camera back in the day, and I gotten a few pictures. I kinda stopped using it since there wasn't anything I could do with the MPO files. However, the camera might gain a new life if I can turn pictures into a CNC carving by grayscale the MPO files. Does anyone know if this is possible and where it is?

BTW I wasn't sure if this is the right subgroup to ask this to. If it isn't, then please kindly direct me to the sub group I should ask such a question to.

Comment: This might be better suited to SE Photography.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not seeing any program for SE Photography. I'm just seeing locations and schools when putting that in Google. Can you link the program you're talking about?
Keep in mind, whatever it is, it has to use the 2 images within the MPO file (left and right image) to make a new one to grayscale to something that can be used in 3D printing or CNC. Thanks btw for looking into this.

Comment: Click on the blue link, it will take you to [SE Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you, I will ask there. Short of this, I am going to look into making my own AI program that can understand depth between the 2 images. That is unless someone else has done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered at another place. There is 2 programs that I know about now.

https://triaxes.com/articles/from-stereo-pair-to-lenticular-print/

http://www.depthmask.com/priceen.html

none so far is that great when it comes to the details